# Marker OnClick; adding custom information into infoWindow by the user

Tags: java, android, google-maps, marker, infowindow

I am creating an app in which a user can place a marker and put inside an infoWindow his own information and a picture from a gallery? Is this possible? Do I use another Activity, where do I store this information?

Comment: I am voting to close this question for being "too broad" - please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

To set a custom marker image, you have to use the image in a bitmap format.

This is an example that add the marker, his custom image and a tittle description:

```
Mymarker = googleMap;
            LatLng markerPosition = new LatLng(Lat, Long);
            BitmapDrawable dr = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image);
            Bitmap bitmapD = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(dr.getBitmap(), 200, 200, false);
            Mymarker.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().snippet("My Snippet").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmapD)).position(markerPosition).title("Marker"));
            Mymarker.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(markerPosition));
```

Comment: im asking if a user can import picture and text into infoWindow, not me